# Can I detect an infinitely nested list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, nested-lists

I've noticed an interesting property of Python objects, which is that they can be self-similar. For example, if you have a list and append itself to it, you'll get a list within a list within a list within a list...

```py
x = []
x.append(x)
print(x)   # displayed as "[[...]]"
```

My question is, can you *detect* whether or not a list is infinitely nested? I tried `x in x`, but that's not foolproof -- the code below prints `False` when it should print `True`:

```py
x = []
x.append(x)
y = [x, x]
print(y in y)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: This is effectively a cycle.

Comment: You can more or less just copy how the list repr itself does that `[...]`.    
 It's fairly simple and easy to understand. 
 https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Objects/object.c#L1945-L1989

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Write a function that iterates through the list, building a reference list of IDs found in the list.  If any ID appears in one of its sub-lists, you have infinite nesting.

Maintain the list of "ancestor" IDs and recur on each element that's a list.

Can you do the coding now?

Comment: That would probably work, but in the extreme cases it might take a while. EDIT: also `RecursionError` might pop up too...

Comment: What sort of "extreme cases" do you envision?  You're trying to find a loop in a tree structure, which is simply a special case of directed graph.  This will take **O(N)** time and space for a tree of `N` nodes.